# Remove query from URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm creating a search engine with wordpress and I want to create a keyword that can be removed onclick.

To be more specific I have:

MyUrl
http://myexemple.com/?sfid=2675&_sft_category=virtualisation-cloud-devops+ms+in

I have something to grab the queries and display them on my page:

```
                <?php
                $motsclefs = $_GET['_sft_category'] ;
                $motsclefsconvert = explode(" ", $motsclefs);
                $classId = 0;
                function get_replace(){

                }
                // If the parameter is given, continue.
                if (isset($_GET['_sft_category'])) {
                    echo ' Mots clefs sélectionnés :&nbsp;';
                } 
                else {    
                    echo 'Pas de mots clefs sélectionnés';
                };

                foreach ($motsclefsconvert as $valuemotsclefsconvert) {
                    //Up the class id by 1
                    $classId++;
                    // Echo the divs
                    echo '<div onclick="this.remove();"  id="mywords" class="' . $classId . '">' . $valuemotsclefsconvert . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>';
                }
                ?>
```

This code is for my search engine. It grabs the queries from my url and displays them on my page.

For the moment they just click on the result and it disappears without any reloading thanks to `this.remove();` on my div. How can I remove the query that they click on and reload the page to refresh the results?

Comment: Maybe [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: You would parse_url($args) ?

Comment: Are `_sft_category` your search keywords?

Comment: nop,_sft_category is a param and my search keywords are : virtualisation-cloud-devops+ms+in. It's them that i want to remove one by one onceclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to add the reload after click on one of your keywords.

You didn't precise if you want to do it *only* in PHP, so I give you a javascript only solution.

```js
/** {string} URL queries in string */
let urlQueriesString = window.location.search,
/** {string[]} URL queries in array */
 urlQueriesArray = urlQueriesString.substring(1).split('&'),
/** {Object.<string, string>} URL queries in object */
 urlQueries = {},
/** {string[]} List of search keywords */
 searchKeywords = [],
/** {HTMLElement[]} List of <li> which will be inserted into DOM */
    liElements;

// Fills in urlQueries object
for (let i in urlQueriesArray) {
 urlQueriesArray[i] = urlQueriesArray[i].split('=');
    
    urlQueries[urlQueriesArray[i][0]] = urlQueriesArray[i][1];
}

// Gets search keywords from _sft_category parameter
searchKeywords = urlQueries._sft_category.split('+'); // or .split(' ')

// Inserts a <li> in the DOM for each keyword
for (let i in searchKeywords) {
 let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
        html = `<li>${searchKeywords[i]}</li>`;
    
    ul.innerHTML += html;
}

// Gets inserted <li>
liElements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Adds an event on click for each <li>
for (let i in liElements) {
    let li = liElements[i];
    
    // Checks instance type because last element of liElements is the length and we don't want to do what's following for this one
    if (li instanceof HTMLElement) {
     // Creates new URL on click
        li.addEventListener('click', function() {
            let url = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname,
                keyword = this.innerText;
                
            searchKeywords = searchKeywords.filter((kw) => (kw !== keyword));
            
            url += urlQueriesString.replace(/_sft_category=[\w\d_+-]+/, `_sft_category=${searchKeywords.join('+')}`);
            
            console.log(url);
            
            // Uncomment next line for reload with new url
            // window.location.href = url;
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

This code snippet could be simplified, but currently it should do the work.

You probably have to adapt it a bit in order for it to work with your project.

Comment: Okey i'm gonna tri this one ! Thanks for your answer iArcadia

Comment: OK ! I tried and you're awesome ! it work very well thanks a lot =) Just a problem, my php already create me some divs, and when i click on it it duplicate me the filter that i want , to be more specific there is screenshots https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/10/4/1551965357-1.png   https://www.noelshack.com/2019-10-4-1551965357-2.png   https://www.noelshack.com/2019-10-4-1551965357-3.png   My problem is that i want the redirection when user click on the brown button (screenshot N°2). Am i clear on my ask ? ^^' (BTW you already did a great job !)

Comment: I am not sure to understand what's happening in your above post

Comment: In fact the brown/grey button is the one that i want to click on to reload my page (in the Screenshot N°2 it is write "CX" on it). Actually your js code is creating a li  once i click on this brown/grey button, but my real need is to directly click on  this "cx" button and reload the page with the new query

Comment: In my snippet, the part where I create `<li>` tags was just to *simulate* your DOM as I can't reproduce it. Do you see my loop `Adds an event on click for each <li>`? You should replace `liElements` by the `<div>` tags you are talking about.

Comment: Oh ok i'm gonna try this one, i'm sure that i can have it !

Comment: Okey iArcadia ! It work like a charm ! Huge thank you for your help you're the best =) (Just a little precision, i add    (function() {})(); In the end of the code to make it load only after the dom loading

Comment: No problem, it was a pleasure! Accept this post as the answer, and you are the best ;)